# I am using update command in my coding as "update table set @colum1=value1, @column2=value2 where

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures, ado.net

When I am using the syntax

```
Update table set @column1=@value1, @column2=@value2
```

---

```
Using cony As New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
cony.Open()
Dim kktarget As String = "target" + yymmc.ToString
Dim kkactual As String = "actual" + yymmc.ToString

Dim query As String = "update tpmkpi set @kktarget =@tg1,@kkactual=@ac1 where rno=@knox"

Using cmdy As New SqlCommand(query, cony)
cmdy.Parameters.Add("@kktarget", SqlDbType.Char).Value = kktarget
cmdy.Parameters.Add("@kkactual", SqlDbType.Char).Value = kkactual
cmdy.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tg1", tg1)
cmdy.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ac1", ac1)
cmdy.Parameters.AddWithValue("@knox", knox)
Dim resulty As Integer = cmdy.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: You cannot parametrize the **column** (or table) names - only the values

Answer (score 0):

The update staement should be like this,

```
update tpmkpi set kktarget =@tg1,kkactual=@ac1 where rno=@knox
```